# What is the recommend way to create a custom culture and associated resource files for a specific Client?

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources, resx, cultureinfo

I have client that wants to specifiy their own version of localized content for a subset of my string resources.

For simplicity here is basic example:
Lets say I have 2 localized strings (showing english content)

PageTitle="Hello World"

PageDescription="This is a more wordy version of Hello World!"

I wish to localize these so I have resource files.

- Strings.resx *(contains my English
  string)*
- Strings.fr-ca.resx
  *(contains my French-Canadian strings)*
- Strings.fr-ca-clientX.resx *(contains
  my strings for a Client whom is
  French-Canadian and therfore very
  picky;) - just joking)*

Ideally "Strings.fr-ca-clientX" can specify only the strings they want to "override".  In other words they may just wish to change the PageTitle and continue using the PageDescription from the "fr-ca" resource file.

So how do I go about this in .NET?  Ideally I would just create the resx file and specify the culture in my "Web.config" and it should work...

```
<globalization uiCulture="fr-ca-clientX" culture="fr-ca-clientX" />
```

However, this does not work.  "The  tag contains an invalid value for the 'culture' attribute" is my first obsticle.

Thanks,

Justin

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this way of providing localization. It is far from easy, but for such demands I would probably create some Resource Facade which will be single point of decision on what strings to load at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void AddCustomCulture(string cultureName, string baseCulture)
    {
        var cultureBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(cultureName, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);

        cultureBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(new CultureInfo(baseCulture));

        var region = baseCulture.Substring(3, 2);

        cultureBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo(region));

        cultureBuilder.Register();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new culture with the following code:

```
        //Get culture info based on Great Britain
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "en-GB" );
        RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo( cultureInfo.Name );

        CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( txtCultureName.Text, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None );

        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo( cultureInfo );
        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo( regionInfo );

        // Custom Changes
        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureEnglishName = txtCultureName.Text;
        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureNativeName = txtNativeName.Text;

        cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();
```

I have written a post on creating an app to do just that..

http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/search/label/Globalization

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to create your own culture and register it. You'll find MSDN article on that topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx).

You don't need to alter culture attribute, it should stay at "fr-CA", as uiCulture attribute is responsible for loading strings from resources.